# Is there any lore about why the Horadric Cube isn't in Diablo 3?

Tags: diablo-series

What happened to the Horadric Cube after Diablo 2? Is it lost forever? Is there a chance to find such a rare item again or has Blizzard said nothing about its disappearance?

Shouldn't the Horadric Cube be with Deckard Cain, since he is one of the last Horadrim?

I'm trying to find if Blizzard did anything for a main story item transition from Diablo 2 to Diablo 3 here. If there are any small pieces of information you could find it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In short, the cube was replaced by the new crafting system. I suspect the reasons for this was to make a system with more accessibility, discoverability, extensibility, and better theme tie-in. Here is [a related question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/68552/is-there-a-horadric-cube-in-diablo-3).

Comment: So it would mean that the item is permanently gone? Is there no lore on what happened to it?

Comment: also, i have no idea why this question is closed. all i'm asking is if blizzard released any lore on the horadric cube for d3 and what happened to it.

Comment: I would suggest editing the question to reflect that. Lore questions are on-topic here, but it looks like this was closed because people weren't sure what you were asking. Sadly, I know of no lore related to the horadric cube.

Comment: Personally, I voted to close because even though lore questions are on topic, questions that essentially require answers that are speculative or negative usually end up being lousy questions.

Comment: how is this speculative? i'm trying to find lore on the Horadric cube, and the answer's either yes, here's the info or no, blizzard didn't do anything of the sort. also, its not like i'm not using google to find it as well, just that my keywords arent hitting anything useful.

Comment: @RenoYeo - "What happened to it" is not a yes or no question.  It's not in the game, nobody can tell you specifically the lore reasons why - it was a gameplay decision and they decided not to address it.

Comment: ah well. i guess there'll never be any lore for the Horadric Cube.

Comment: The question was confusing as well; 'now that its in Diablo 3' ?? When it **isn't** in D3.

Comment: I edited the question title and body to reflect what it seems Reno is trying to ask. I think it's a good question, but that unfortunately there's no relevant lore (unless the novels or comics cover this).

Comment: If you find the right satchel ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Horadric Cube is not in Diablo 3.  Given the Diablo series tries to extrapolate from a  character having performed the actions in previous Diablos, my assumption due to the lack of evidence is that it remained in the possession of the hero who killed Diablo and Baal 20 years earlier until they passed away.

The Horadric Cube would not have magically made its way back to Deckard Cain unless it was specifically handed to him.  After all, he wasn't in possession of it in Diablo 2.